# Python Regex: Find pattern, even if repeated, with re.split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find a way to detect `,` and `or` in a string even if they are repeated. So even a string such as `one ,   ,  or   or,  two` with re.split() should return "one" and "two".

So far this is what I have (Using Python 3.10):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\s*,\s*or\s*|\s*,\s*|\s+or\s+)+", flags=re.I)
string = "one,two or three   ,   four   or   five  or , or six , oR   ,  seven, ,,or,   ,, eight or qwertyor orqwerty,"
result = re.split(pattern, string)
print(result)
```

which returns:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'qwertyor orqwerty', '']
```

My issue so far is if I have consecutive `or`, my pattern will only recognize every other `or`. For example:

```
string = "one or or two"
>>> ['one', 'or two']

string = "one or or or two"
>>> ['one', 'or', 'two']
```

Notice in the first example the second element contains `or` and in the second example `or` is an element by itself.

Is there a way to get around this? Also if there is a better way of separating these strings that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Try `(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b))+\s*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "one,two or three   ,   four   or   five  or , or six , oR   ,  seven, ,,or,   ,, eight or qwertyor orqwerty,"
print( re.split(r'(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b))+\s*', text.rstrip().rstrip(',')) )
# => ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'oR', 'seven', 'eight', 'qwertyor orqwerty']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YhFCyZ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNrehL/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\s*(?:,|\bor\b))+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:,|\bor\b)` - either a comma or a whole word `or`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Note the use of [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970), this is crucial since you are using the pattern in `re.split`.

Also, note the `text.rstrip().rstrip(',')` so that there is no trailing empty item in the result.

Answer (score -1):

Does Python support the word boundary flag `\b`? If so, you could probably simplify the regular expression to something along the following lines:

```
\s*((,|\bor\b)\s*)+
```